# jQuery selection not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following code to run when value is entered to an input. The event is triggered when the focus goes out from the input.

```
$("#guest-level option[id='"+ result.BookingInfo.guestLevelCode +"']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

This doesn't get executed in chrome but works perfectly in firefox. How can I fix this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

```
  $("#guest-level option[id='"+ result.BookingInfo.guestLevelCode +"']")
   .prop("selected", true);
```

ShortCut:- Ids are supposed to be unique.

So

```
 $("#"+ result.BookingInfo.guestLevelCode).prop("selected", true);
```